# CSS ID Selector not working but Class Selector does

Tags: asp.net, css

I am having a problem in that a style is not being applied when I used an "ID" selector (#btnOK). However, if I use a class selector (.btnOK, by changing the "#btnOK" to a ".btnOK" in the CSS file), the style is applied.

Any idea why? The style IS also applied in design mode, but  not at run time. It's findingf the css file, else, the class wouldn't be applied. Case sensitivity match on the ID.

In the web page:

```
<link href="CSS/CvCost.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<asp:Button ID="btnOK" CssClass="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" ValidationGroup="Add"/>
```

In CSS/CvCost.css:

```
#btnOK{
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:right;
    width:75px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: can you post the *actual* HTML?

Comment: view the source code of the rendered html page.. I believe the id of server-side tags gets modified to something that the asp.net engines understands..

Comment: Your're question was enough to lead me to the answer. The btn control has been renamed to ctl00_phPageContent_btnOK. Hmmm...It looks to me as though ID selectors aren't going to be very convenient when I use master pages. Sugegstions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.Net will automatically generate unique IDs based on the element's container.

You need to use ASP.Net's actual ClientID.
Since you can't do that in an external CSS file, you should just use a class selector.

If you're using ASP.Net 4, you can also set the new [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28VS.100%29.aspx) property to `Static`.

Comment: That's good to know about the ClientIDMode property, thx. I'm looking fwd to the release in March.

Comment: I try the same as what you trying to do & yeah it's difficult to get it done, so I switch to class to get as what I want. Style ID will work just fine with non .Net object, maybe someone can explain why.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly the ID that will show up when the code is ran/debugged wouldn't be the same as #btnOK.  VS will give it another ID to go by when the code is ran.